# How to call a function of a smart contract with Ethers.rs?

Tags: rust, ethereum

I'm using `ethers.rs` & want to call a function of a deployed smart contract. I don't to use the ABI of smart contract for this.

Based on my research so far I've found a way of using the **function selector**. This has to be encoded along with the function arguments in the `data` field of the transaction.

How can I do so using ethers.rs if I just know the contract address & the function that I want to call?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to parse your contract abi with abigen:

```rust
abigen!(ERC20Token, "./erc20.json",);
```

more information [here](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/tree/master/examples/contracts)

next you create your contract object:

```rust
let contract = ERC20Token::new(address, client);
```

and finally you call it:

```rust
contract.total_supply().call().await

contract.transfer(to, amount).call().await
```

you can check the full example [here](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/blob/master/examples/contracts/examples/abigen.rs)